# How to query how much file attachments space is used by User

Tags: apex, soql, user-management

I have an requirment where i would like to know the current limit used by User for File Attachment and send it as csv files to the buisness. I am not finding a way where i can see fetch that space used.

I know salesforce provide following way to look at that for each user. Can i get that for all users in any csv file through dataloader or soql.

```
Click Your Name | Setup | Manage Users | Users.
Click the name of any user.
Click View next to the Used Data Space or Used File Space fields
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following query seems to work to see how many bytes worth of Attachments a particular user has:

```
select Owner.Name, SUM(BodyLength) SpaceUsed from Attachment group by Owner.Name
```

Note that the space used metric on the User also includes `ContentDocument`, so you might need to run a the same query against that object as well if you use `ContentDocument`.

Comment: Thanks Illusive, will it give values in MB, which each user in using.

Comment: @DavidMycka On further inspection, it looks like `BodyLength` is in bytes.  It's also appears larger than what might show up on the User object based on comparing the two in my org, probably because the User object divides by 1048576 (1024 * 1024).  Unfortunately I don't think that SOQL has a way to modify a field before returning it.

Comment: However, it would probably be pretty straightforward to write a scheduled job that takes the result of this query, puts the results in a csv file with the desired precision and sends an email to the relevant parties.

Comment: Thanks IllusiveBrian, Can we think that BodyLength will give apporximation of total bytes used by user. And BodyLength divides by 1024 will give us approximate MB user holds. Correct?.

Comment: @DavidMycka This query should be precisely accurate in terms of total number of bytes used by a user (although note that you would also need to query `ContentDocument` as well if you want the full count, and I don't know how versioning comes into play).  If you want MB, you should divide by 1048576.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was wondering as requirement is only to send Attachments space used by user( Maximum Default is  25Mb by Salesforce). So why would we need to query ContentDocument also, wouldn't quering Attachment as your first query will be fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68491/discussion-between-david-mycka-and-illusivebrian).